# SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"] being returned unevaluated

Tags: social-media

When I typed the command

```
 SocialMediaData["Facebook", "FriendNetwork"]
```

I got the output

> ```
> SocialMediaData[Facebook, FriendNetwork"]
> ```

I have the latest Paclet. I am using *Mathematica* on Raspbian on my pi.

Please can you tell me what I need to do to get `SocialMediaData` to work.

Comment: some ideas: is the " at the end of FriendNetwork a typo? are you connected to the internet? are you logged into Facebook?

Answer (score 1):

Certain requests, like that one, are no longer supported by Facebook's new API.

If the documentation for SocialMediaData hasn't been updated, then you'll want to check Facebook's documentation for the API to see what is and isn't possible their new API.

Comment: Perhaps including [link to the blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2015/04/14/wolframalpha-personal-analytics-for-facebook-last-chance-to-analyze-your-friend-network/) is helpful in your answer.